Gulp Responsive not generating images
Error: Created 0 images (matched 1 of 1 image).
Here is my script:
const gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('src/*.png')
    .pipe(
      $.responsive({
        '*.png': { width: 200 }
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out'))
});

Dir structure:
src/
  image.png

This is on ubuntu. On Mac I am getting unsupported image format.
